# Edit and delete row functionality in datatables using jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I had to design a table view using datatables and bootstrap which has the following view
[image]

I added values to table by using the following code

```
function updateTable(){
     var content = $.ajax(
      {
       url:"http://192.168.1.2:8080/alpharithm/employee/employeeDetails",
       dataType:"json",
        type:"GET",            


        success : function(data) {



         var arr1= [];
            var arr= new Array();
            $.each( data, function(i, obj) {
                     arr = obj;
                     arr1.push(arr);

            });

        console.log(arr1[0]);       



         $('#employeeTable').dataTable( {

          "aaData":arr1,
          "destroy":true,
           /*"columns": [
              { "data": "employee_id" },
              { "data": "division" },
              { "data": "first_name" },
              { "data": "mobile_number" },
              { "data": "home_number" },
              { "data": "company_mail" },
              { "data": "personal_mail" },
              { "data": "date_of_birth" },
              { "data": "date_of_joining" },
              { "data": "blood_group" },
              { "data": "emergency_contact" },
              { "data": "emergency_phone" },
              { "data": "permanent_address" },
              { "data": "current_address" },
              { "data": "bank_name" },
              { "data": "bank_branch" },
              { "data": "banck_account_no" },
              { "data": "pancard_no" },
              { "data": "" },
              { "data": "" }

              ],*/
           "aoColumns": [{
              "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "employee_id"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData":  "division"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "first_name",
            "mRender":function(data, type, full){
                  return full.first_name +" "+ full.last_name ;
                   }
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "mobile_number"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "home_number"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "company_mail"
              },{
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "personal_mail"
              },{
            "mData": "date_of_birth"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData":  "date_of_joining"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "blood_group"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "emergency_contact"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "emergency_phone"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "permanent_address"
              },{
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "current_address"
              },{
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "bank_name"
              },{
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData": "bank_branch"
              }, {
            "mData": "banck_account_no"
              }, {
            "sWidth": "5%",
            "mData":  "pancard_no"
              },
                          {
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
              return '<img class="img-table" src="images/user.png" alt="image">';
                            }
              },  
              {
            "mData": null,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
              return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="editTableBtn" href="#" >Edit</a>&nbsp<a id="deleteTableBtn" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Delete</a>';
            }
              }],
           "iDeferLoading": 57
           });


        }


      });

  }
```

I want to edit and delete and edit each row separately.I tried many methods but edit an delete is not working. How to Edit and delete rows separately? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please update the code in fiddle or plunker, so that we can help you.

Comment: How would you like to edit?? in a modal or in the place where you displayed the complete details with image??

Comment: In modal view.I used editor datatable for modal view but its not working.

Comment: @stanze this is JSFiddle Link   http://jsfiddle.net/GokulRGG/tzo66uwj/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#employeeTable a.delete').on('click', function(e) {
```

The above line is not working, because the delete button is dynamic created, you may use

```
 $('#employeeTable').on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
```

instead

Besides, your delete and edit button are inside the detail panel, you cannot just simply use

```
var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
```

to delete the whole record, because nRow is the expanded detail panel only, if you investigate using the chrome inspector/firebug, you would see that, once you clicked the "+" detail button, a  with class "child" will be append to your target row.

One of the solution you may try is

```
$('#employeeTable').on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
    var parent = $(nRow).prev();
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(parent);
});
```

I guess there may be some better approach other than using $(nRow).prev() to get its parent row

Demo link:
http://jsfiddle.net/s5k4hL0v/